# Examples of potentials for which Schrödinger equation lacks discrete points in continuous spectrum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In Landau, Lifshitz, "Quantum Mechanics, non-relativistic theory" in $\S18$ "The fundamental properties of Schrödinger's equation" the following is said in a footnote:

> it must be mentioned that, for some particular mathematical forms of the function $U(x,y,z)$ (which have no physical significance), a discrete set of values may be absent from the otherwise continuous spectrum.

I wonder, what are the examples of such mathematical forms of potential?

Comment: Do you mean *real physical* potentials or mathematically constructed ones?

Comment: @draks... I mean any such functions, but preferably not as strange as e.g. Dirichlet function :) I do understand that there're no such physical potentials: L&L already say such functions have no physical significance.

Comment: In the German translation (which is according to my experience more accurate than the English one) the corresponding statement reads that there my be some part of the discrete spectrum added (not lacking) to the continuum spectrum. I would know how to construct such potentials. I guess we have to wait for somebody knowing Russian to determine which is the statement intended by Landau and Lifshitz (in the end the Russian version is the authority) --- as Ruslan sounds Russian, do you have a Russian copy of Landau-Lifshitz?

Comment: @Fabian yeah, I first read it in the Russian copy, just cited English one so that it's more accessible to readers of this site. In Russian version the wording is similar to English translation: "...из непрерывного спектра может выпадать дискретный набор значений". "Выпадать из" in this context means "to lack from".

Comment: Is L&L referring to the singularity at the origin in the Newtonian gravitation, coulomb, or Biot-Savart potentials? Also, when solving for harmonic oscillator eigenfunctions we enforce some reality conditions and exclude a set of mathematically valid solutions. I should go read L&L again to remember the context.

Comment: @JEM L&L talk about general properties of Schrödinger equation in potential, which vanishes at infinity. They say that "for $E>0$ the equation has no solutions for which the integral $\int |\psi|^2dV$ converges", and the citation in the OP is a footnote for this phrase. As for harmonic oscillator, we just impose boundary conditions of boundedness at infinities and solve the BVP. No mathematically valid solution of this BVP is excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been satisfactorily [answered on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/192293/29747). Here's it, for reference:

> The spectrum of an operator is always a closed set.  But perhaps they are defining the "continuous spectrum" to be all points of the spectrum that are not in the point spectrum (i.e. not eigenvalues).  Then there can be eigenvalues surrounded by continuous spectrum.  The classic example of this in a Schrödinger operator is due to Wigner and von Neumann.  See e.g. [this recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4840) of Milivoje Lukic.

For completeness, here's the Wigner–von Neumann example (description taken from [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039698936026) and reshaped a bit).

Consider 3D radial Schrödinger equation

$$-\frac1{r^2}\frac d{dr}\left(r^2\frac d\psi(r){dr}\right)+q(r)\psi(r)=\lambda\psi(r),$$

where

$$q(r)=\frac{-32\sin(r)\left(g(r)^3\cos r-3g(r)^2\sin^3 r+g(r)\cos r+\sin^3 r\right)}{(1+g(r)^2)^2}$$

with $g(r)=2r-\sin(2r).$

The Hamiltonian here obviously has continuous spectrum from $0$ to $+\infty$. But there's also an eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ with the following eigenfunction:

$$\psi(r)=\frac{\sin r}{r\left(1+g(r)^2\right)},$$

which it's easy to see is square integrable with weight of $r^2$.